# Resolves fake hostnames?

Tags: ruby

I created this DNS lookup script, and it's doing some very strange things. The relevant code:

```
  def resolver
    begin
      Resolv.each_address(@host) do |ip|
        if ip == false
          puts "Failed to resolve address"
        else
          puts ip
        end
      end
    rescue ArgumentError
      puts "You must specify a hostname."
    end
  end
```

All of it works as expected, except for one part. If I enter in nonsense, for example: fdjafaldjfafbfda, it successfully resolves an address. Every time it's the same address, even if the random garbage I type in is different. I want to understand why this is happening. I'm assuming it has something to do with the if ip == false part of the code.

Comment: Running `require 'resolv'; Resolv.each_address('garbage'){|ip| p ip };` in IRB or Pry prints no result for me. Does it for you?

Comment: Try 8.8.8.8 (Google) as your DNS host. They will not try and hijack unknown addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run a slightly modified version of your example

```
require 'resolv'

def resolver(host)
    begin
      puts "resolving \"#{host}\""
      Resolv.each_address(host) do |ip|
        if ip == false
          puts "Failed to resolve address"
        else
          puts ip
        end
      end
    rescue ArgumentError
      puts "You must specify a hostname."
    end
  end

resolver(ARGV[0])
```

with

```
  ruby resolve.rb www.stackoverflow.fake.domain
```

I get not IP address, as expected. If running this gives a different result for you, you might have run into a "feature" of your DNS provider. E.g. Verisign changed its lookup policy back in 2003 - when someone queried a non-existant domain, he was redirected to a Verisign ad page instead, see [Slashdot discussion on Verisign policy from 2003](http://slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=52568&cid=0&pid=0&startat=&threshold=5&op=Change)

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Perhaps you are right. Looking up the IP address it gives out, I find and organization and net name of Search Guide. Must be some sort of redirection. Running the above code provided by p11y I find it returns the same IP address as it has been with my code. So it's obviously something to do with the DNS provider. Interesting.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it (using the checkmark button).